# Какие настройки надо поменять в конфигурации my.ini, чтобы изменить папку, где хранятся базы данных?

Tags: mysql

Я слышал, что менять надо datadir.

Я изменил на другую папку. Скопировал в нее свои базы. Поставил datadir обратно, удалил базы данных со старого места через PhpMyAdmin (ведь теперь мои базы в новом месте, зачем они мне в старом). Снова поставил datadir на новое место. Захожу в PhpMyAdmin - базы есть. Открываю какую-нибудь базу, пытаюсь открыть у нее таблицу, и мне выдается ошибка, что таблицы не существует. Если запустить сайт, в котором используется данная база, то полетят исключения о том, что таблицы не существуют.

Если не удалять базы со старого места, то все нормально работает.

Как я понял, мало изменить datadir, нужно еще какую-то настройку. Но какую?

Comment: Перепривязать все tablespace.

Comment: @Akina, можете дать ссылку, где написано, как это делается?

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Copying Tablespaces to Another Instance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tablespace-copying.html). Там рассказывается про перенос на другой сервер - но какая в принципе разница?

Comment: @Akina, я вместе с datadir поменял innodb_data_home_dir. И все стало работать отлично!

У меня вопрос. Если я буду создавать не innodb, а другие типы таблиц, все будет нормально? Вообще, может ли такое произойти, что я работаю, работаю, все отлично. А потом мне говорят, что срочно нужно что-то доделать. Я хочу доделать это дома, а у меня не некорректно работает БД, так как помимо datadir и innodb_data_home_dir нужно было поменять что-то еще.

Хотелось бы заранее узнать, что поменять. И сразу поменять. Чтобы не обжигаться.

Comment: *я вместе с datadir поменял innodb_data_home_dir. И все стало работать отлично!* то есть Вы переместили вообще всю директорию данных? я думал, речь идёт о каталоге одной БД...